# bson.errors.InvalidBSON: date value out of range

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bson

I need your help. I am fetching data from a mongoDb server using Python. While fetching data I encounter an error.

```
 drivers = mongodb_global('drivers')
    filter_col = {
        "created": 1,
        "updated": 1,
        "_id": 1,
        "name": 1,
        "birthday": 1,
        "id_expiry": 1,
        "license_expiry": 1
    }

    data = drivers.find({}, filter_col)
    driver_lst = []
    for item in data:
        print(item)
```

**"return EPOCH_NAIVE + datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds,
bson.errors.InvalidBSON: date value out of range"**

I have searched everywhere but couldn't find a solution. the problem is that I am getting an error at  the **db.find({})** stage, so I am unable to handle this error in the later stages of the pipeline. Could you please guide me, how to handle this error?

I have tried to solve this error but not solved.

Comment: Is there any document with invalid date format or null value in your collection ?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have null values in it as well. In fact, I have almost 50% values null in date field.

Comment: This [answer from the `pymongo` FAQ](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-do-i-get-overflowerror-decoding-dates-stored-by-another-language-s-driver) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle the exception like:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo.errors import InvalidBSON

drivers = mongodb_global('drivers')
filter_col = {
    "created": 1,
    "updated": 1,
    "_id": 1,
    "name": 1,
    "birthday": 1,
    "id_expiry": 1,
    "license_expiry": 1
}

data = drivers.find({}, filter_col)
driver_lst = []

for item in data:
    try:
        print(item)
    except InvalidBSON as e:
        print(f"Invalid document: {e}")
```

Comment: Got same Error:
    return EPOCH_NAIVE + datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds,
bson.errors.InvalidBSON: date value out of range

Comment: Okay, then try to block the documents that have null dates for being processed.
Exp: 
from datetime import datetime

for item in data:
   if item["birthday"] is not None and isinstance(item["birthday"], datetime):
        # Process the "birthday" field
    else:
        print("Skipping document with invalid or null birthday")

Comment: But I don't want to skip those records I want to read all records from the collections. The 50% data is going be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

This is so strange.
Your code above try to simply return documents with specific columns, so that should work even if there is no validity check of the date column. I have tried the same code on the following collection and it does work :

```
import pymongo      
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://xxx:xxxx@localhost:27017/?authMechanism=DEFAULT"
filter_col = {
    "address": 1,
    "date": 1,
    "_id": 1,
}

db = client["test"]  
collection = db["customers"]

data = collection.find({}, filter_col)

for item in data:
    print(item)
```

It returns this:

```
python .\script.py
{'_id': ObjectId('652bef9a87af75d75bc425ca'), 'address': 'Apple st 652', 'date': None}
{'_id': ObjectId('652bef9a87af75d75bc425cb'), 'address': 'Mountain 21', 'date': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 15, 16, 54, 40)}
{'_id': ObjectId('652bef9a87af75d75bc425cc'), 'address': 'Valley 345'}
```

[image]